# call startActivityForResult from another activity

Tags: android, android-intent

I have an Activity A which calls startActivityForResult to start Activity B, normally user can click a button from Activity A to start Activity B for result.

Now I'm need to open Activity B from Activity C, when Activity B returns, it should go back to Activity A. Is this possible?

I'm trying to use an intent to start Activity A from Activity C and call A's startActivityForResult method, but it seems impossible to get the instance of Activity A.

The normal stack is A->B but now I want it to be C->B, but when B returns, it return result to A.

I'm thinking if there is a possible way to do C->A->B but hide A from user?

Comment: why not just launch activity B and when the result is returned to activity C launch an intent to activity A with the result data? Do you have control of activity B? Activity A's instance is not accessible because it could have been paused, resumed, destroyed etc depending on the use of system resources.

Comment: It's possible sure but if B is launched from C, A will not know the result of B

Comment: is C launched from A? Or are you trying to confuse your users?

Answer (score 2):

This is a very clever question. I think Kevin's answer is the right way to go, although I do want to add about the subject:

First we need to understand the Activity's launch mode. In android there are 3 activity launch modes:

1. **Standard Mode**: This is the default mode, where a new `Activity` will always be created to work separately with each `Intent` sent.
2. **Single Top Mode**:  This mode acts almost the same as the standard mode, only difference is if there already is an `Activity` instance with the same type at the top of stack in the *caller Task*, a new `Activity` will **not** be created (an `Intent` will be sent to an existing `Activity` through `onNewIntent()` method).
3. **Single Task Mode**: This mode is quite different from `standard` and `singleTop`. An `Activity` with `singleTask launchMode` is allowed to have only **one** instance.

Basically, we can assign a `launchMode` directly as an attribute inside the `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<activity
        android:name=".SingleTaskActivity"
        android:label="singleTask launchMode"
        android:launchMode="singleTask">
</activity>
```

As for your question, assuming we stick with the *Standard laucnhMode*, the only workaround I can think of to achieve what you want, will be to call the `finish()` method after each call to `startActivity()` **which is not** `ActivityA`. For example, supposing I'm inside `ActivityC`:

```
public void buttonClick(View view) {

        switch (((Button) view).getText().toString()) {
            case "A":
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ActivityA.class));
                break;

            case "B":
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ActivityB.class));
                finish();
                break;

            case "C":
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ActivityC.class));
                finish();
                break;
        }
    }
```

This way, no matter where I hit "back", I will always return to `ActivityA`.
I understand this may not solve your problem, but I hope that it does leave you with a few more ways of thinking.

Let me know if this was of any help for you at all, if not simply comment and I'll edit my post.

Answer (score 1):

So your stack is A-C-B, and you want it to just be A?  This is as simple as calling `finish()` in C's `onActivityResult(...)` when it receives a result from B.  This could be any result, or some particular result.  And it could return this result to A.

You can't reliably get the instance of Activity A, because when A is in the background or backstack, there's no guarantee that there is any instance to get.  It could have been persisted and destroyed.

Comment: The normal stack is A->B
but now I want it to be C->B, but when B returns, it return result to A. Is it possible to do C->A->B but hide A from user?

Answer (score 1):

just add getActivity() before start for result

```
getActivity().startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```